# Error in creating a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm using `CodeBlocks` and getting error. Is there something wrong with that?

```
char* tetris = new char[N][M];/here I'm getting error
cin >> tetris[i][j];
if (tetris[i][j] =='.')
```

I want to check if my char array has the following character.

Comment: I guess you mean `if(tetris[i][j]=='.')`.

Comment: What is `tetris`? What's your input? Please provide a [mcve]. Besides, Code::Blocks is just an IDE, and it doesn't matter which one you are using. The relevant thing, in case, is the compiler (probably gcc/mingw)

Comment: If you get an error, it's always much more helpful to show that error(copy paste it into the question without changing it), so people reading it can figure out what's going on. In this case you also need to post more code, like how your `tetris` variable is declared, right now we don't know if this is an array of strings or just single chars or something else.

Comment: okay, I'll keep that in mind! But even I can't see the error 'cause my logs are hidden?!(It's not from the settings)

Comment: in codeblocks, the build tab down the bottom of the screen will show build errors when you hit F9 or click the gear or choose from the build menu etc. these errors will help you (and us) solve the problem. a quick guess; a M and N defined somewhere?

Comment: yes, they are defined above like that (cin>>M; cin>>N;).

Answer (score 1):

The code "char* tetris = new char[N][M];" is incorrect.

You need to specify the size when allocating the memory.

Example:

```
 char *tetris = new char[N*M];
```

Also you declared a char array/pointer and trying to use as 2D array.
You need to either use arrar  of pointers or double pointer, if you want
to use array of strings.

Comment: `new char(N*M)` create one unique char with value `N*M`... You probably want `new char[N*M]` but then `tetris[i][j]` would be invalid syntax too.